Не создается API в кабинете разработчика
Захожу на https://developer.tech.yandex.com/ нажимаю на Подключить API, выбираю Tiles API и выходит ошибка "Не удается загрузить форму"
Могу выбирать любой продукт, везде выходит ошибка о форме. В чем может быть причина?

Если ваш вопрос не решён, проверьте, пожалуйста:

Сохраняется ли ситуация в режиме Инкогнито?
Воспроизводится ли она в других браузерах?

Если ситуация сохраняется по обоим пунктам, напишите, пожалуйста, в поддержку на почту maps-api@support.yandex.ru. Создадим ключ для вас.
